# Make the percentages in line with the background

Tags: css

The percentages are somehow displaced. They should be in line with the pink background. And they may overlap the pink background. What can I try next?

```css
:root {
  --color-0: #054B71;
  --color-1: #E3519A;
  --color-3: black;
  --color-4: white;
  --color-5: #FAA1CD;
}

.n-yes-no-polls-wrapper {
  border-top: 1px solid var(--color-1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-1);
  margin-top: 5rem;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  display: block;
}

.n-yes-no-question {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
}

.n-yes-no-answer-hover:hover {
  background-color: var(--color-5);
  transition: 1s;
}

.n-yes-no-answer,
.n-yes-no-answer-result {
  display: table-cell;
}

.n-yes-no-answer {
  border: 1px solid var(--color-1) !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 48%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.n-yes-no-table {
  border-collapse: separate !important;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-spacing: 0.5rem !important;
  display: table;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.n-yes-no-answer-result {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
}

.n-yes-no-percentage {
  font-size: small;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: var(--color-3);
  color: var(--color-4);
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 1rem;
  line-height: 0.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.n-yes-percentage {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.n-no-percentage {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.n-yes-no-percentage-background,
.n-answer-diagram-yes,
.n-answer-diagram-no {
  background-color: var(--color-1);
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
}

.n-answer-text {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

.n-user-choice::after {
  content: "\00A0\2713";
}

.n-table-row {
  display: table-row;
}


/* ----------------------------------------------
     * Generated by Animista on 2021-10-31 20:29:45
     * Licensed under FreeBSD License.
     * See http://animista.net/license for more info. 
     * w: http://animista.net, t: @cssanimista
     * ---------------------------------------------- */


/**
     * ----------------------------------------
     * animation scale-up-hor-left
     * ----------------------------------------
     */

.scale-up-hor-left {
  -webkit-animation: scale-up-hor-left 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
  animation: scale-up-hor-left 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scale-up-hor-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.4);
    transform: scaleX(0.4);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes scale-up-hor-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.4);
    transform: scaleX(0.4);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<figure class=" lazyloaded" data-link="http://galina/wp-content/themes/nonverbis_journalx/static/css/yes-no-1.css" data-script="http://galina/wp-content/themes/nonverbis_journalx/static/js/yes-no-1.js">
  <span class="n-yes-no-polls-wrapper">
                            <span class="n-yes-no-question">Do you use Instagram?</span>
  <span class="n-yes-no-table">                                                         
                                    <span class="n-table-row">
                                        <span class="n-yes-no-answer-result n-yes-answer-result">
                                            <span style="width: 89%;" class="n-yes-no-percentage-background n-hidden">&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="n-yes-no-percentage n-yes-percentage n-hidden">91&nbsp;%</span>
  </span>
  <span class="n-yes-no-answer-result n-no-answer-result">                                            
                                            <span style="width: 7%;" class="n-yes-no-percentage-background n-hidden">&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="n-yes-no-percentage n-no-percentage n-hidden">9&nbsp;%</span>
  </span>
  </span>

  <span class="n-table-row">
                                        <span class="n-yes-no-answer n-yes-no-answer-hover n-yes-answer">
                                            <span class="n-answer-text">Sure</span>
  </span>
  <span class="n-yes-no-answer n-yes-no-answer-hover n-no-answer">
                                            <span class="n-answer-text">No...</span>
  </span>
  </span>

  </span>
  </span>
  <!-- .n-yes-no-polls-wrapper -->
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the margin, and specify the absolute positioning of those percentages, `top: 0;`.

```css
:root {
  --color-0: #054B71;
  --color-1: #E3519A;
  --color-3: black;
  --color-4: white;
  --color-5: #FAA1CD;
}

.n-yes-no-polls-wrapper {
  border-top: 1px solid var(--color-1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-1);
  margin-top: 5rem;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  display: block;
}

.n-yes-no-question {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
}

.n-yes-no-answer-hover:hover {
  background-color: var(--color-5);
  transition: 1s;
}

.n-yes-no-answer,
.n-yes-no-answer-result {
  display: table-cell;
}

.n-yes-no-answer {
  border: 1px solid var(--color-1) !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 48%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.n-yes-no-table {
  border-collapse: separate !important;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-spacing: 0.5rem !important;
  display: table;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.n-yes-no-answer-result {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
}

.n-yes-no-percentage {
  font-size: small;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: var(--color-3);
  color: var(--color-4);
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.2;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.n-yes-percentage,
.n-no-percentage {
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.n-yes-no-percentage-background,
.n-answer-diagram-yes,
.n-answer-diagram-no {
  background-color: var(--color-1);
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
}

.n-answer-text {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

.n-user-choice::after {
  content: "\00A0\2713";
}

.n-table-row {
  display: table-row;
}


/* ----------------------------------------------
     * Generated by Animista on 2021-10-31 20:29:45
     * Licensed under FreeBSD License.
     * See http://animista.net/license for more info. 
     * w: http://animista.net, t: @cssanimista
     * ---------------------------------------------- */


/**
     * ----------------------------------------
     * animation scale-up-hor-left
     * ----------------------------------------
     */

.scale-up-hor-left {
  -webkit-animation: scale-up-hor-left 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
  animation: scale-up-hor-left 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scale-up-hor-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.4);
    transform: scaleX(0.4);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes scale-up-hor-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.4);
    transform: scaleX(0.4);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<figure class=" lazyloaded" data-link="http://galina/wp-content/themes/nonverbis_journalx/static/css/yes-no-1.css" data-script="http://galina/wp-content/themes/nonverbis_journalx/static/js/yes-no-1.js">
  <span class="n-yes-no-polls-wrapper">
                            <span class="n-yes-no-question">Do you use Instagram?</span>
  <span class="n-yes-no-table">                                                         
                                    <span class="n-table-row">
                                        <span class="n-yes-no-answer-result n-yes-answer-result">
                                            <span style="width: 89%;" class="n-yes-no-percentage-background n-hidden">&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="n-yes-no-percentage n-yes-percentage n-hidden">91&nbsp;%</span>
  </span>
  <span class="n-yes-no-answer-result n-no-answer-result">                                            
                                            <span style="width: 7%;" class="n-yes-no-percentage-background n-hidden">&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="n-yes-no-percentage n-no-percentage n-hidden">9&nbsp;%</span>
  </span>
  </span>

  <span class="n-table-row">
                                        <span class="n-yes-no-answer n-yes-no-answer-hover n-yes-answer">
                                            <span class="n-answer-text">Sure</span>
  </span>
  <span class="n-yes-no-answer n-yes-no-answer-hover n-no-answer">
                                            <span class="n-answer-text">No...</span>
  </span>
  </span>

  </span>
  </span>
  <!-- .n-yes-no-polls-wrapper -->
</figure>
```

Comment: There is some progress. But there has still been a problem: the numbers will not be aligned vertically. They will be stuck to the top.

Comment: @Kifsif, not sure what you mean numbers will not be aligned? Aligned relative to what?

Comment: Updated the height to ```100%```, this what you mean?

Comment: No. n-yes-no-percentage should not be 100 %. But it should be aligned vertically in the middle of n-table-row.

Comment: @Kifsif, Check this https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/MWEMQoo as posted in comment as well.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan, that's what I initially had. Just updated it because while it looks ok on Chrome, in Firefox it is off. Likely because we are talking about odd amount of pixels.

Comment: @Kifsif, maybe you can use transform: ```top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);``` as updated in the answer? This is how you can vertically center absolute positioned elements.